# What chronological order are the Fate video games in?

Tags: fate

I wanted to play Fate but I found there are lot of games in the series. So, what is the Fate video game series' chronological order?

Comment: Reading the plots doesn't really lead me to believe there is one... Or at least one that is really obvious, as I assume time does still exist in the Fate universe... What's wrong with playing them in release order and is there anything to indicate release order is not chronological? (I've never played them)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The simplest answer is *Fate*, *Fate: Undiscovered Realms*, *Fate: The Traitor Soul*, then *Fate: The Cursed King*. Realize that it's a little more complicated than that, so read on for more information.

**The answer to your question isn't really defined. It depends on the person.** I'll explain it with minimum spoilers, hopefully none.

The four Fate games are [Fate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fate_(video_game)), [Fate: Undiscovered Realms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fate:_Undiscovered_Realms), [Fate: The Traitor Soul](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fate:_The_Traitor_Soul), and [Fate: The Cursed King](http://www.gamefaqs.com/pc/625640-fate-the-cursed-king). These are listed in the order they were released: 2005, 2008, 2009, and 2011 respectively.

***Fate*** sets the scene of everything, and will introduce a lot of stuff that will be in *Undiscovered Realms* and *The Traitor Soul*. This is technically the first game, where you start in the town of Grove.

***Undiscovered Realms*** is technically the second game, as it starts directly after you beat *Fate*.

***The Traitor Soul*** can be played at any time with no story defects at all, because the story line doesn't connect with the other games. You are, however in an area of the game introduced in *Undiscovered Realms* though, and you can still play the character from the first two games (You also have the choice of 3 other characters besides the one from the first two games).

***The Cursed King*** has no conection to any of the other 3 games except the gameplay, and the character you play.

- So these games can be played in any order, but for those who like to keep the story perfectly smooth, should play *Fate*, then *Fate: Undiscovered Realms*, and then *Fate: The Traitor Soul*. *Fate: The Cursed King* doesn't have any relevance, so this one can't properly be put into the list, except at the end for simplicity's sake.